# Regular Expression to find substring in html image src

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to scrape different data in websites. 
I am trying to scrape the source, but not all the source, just the substring which is important for me.

For example, in this item, I would like to pick just the string between / and .png (which in this case is "nyt") and to save it in a list.

```
<image width="185" height="26" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xlink:href="https://a1.nyt.com/assets/shell/20160613-034030/images/foundation/logos/nyt-logo-185x26.svg" src="https://a1.nyt.com/assets/shell/20160613-034030/images/foundation/logos/nyt.png" border="0"></image>
```

I have been trying with several regular expressions like re.search('[a-z]*.png',src).group(0) but nothing works well.

Can anyone tell me what would be the right way to scrape that info??

Comment: can you tell us what exact part of the string you want to extract ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the name of the png inside of the `src` attribute you can use this regular expression:

```
src=\s*(\"|\')[^"']+?([^/]+?)\.png\1
```

You will have to capture the second group in Python in this case.

Click on the [pythex link](https://pythex.org/?regex=src%3D%5Cs*(%5C%22%7C%5C%27)%5B%5E%22%27%5D%2B%3F(%5B%5E%2F%5D%2B%3F)%5C.png%5C1&test_string=%3Cimage%20width%3D%22185%22%20height%3D%2226%22%20%0Axmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20%0Axlink%3Ahref%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fa1.nyt.com%2Fassets%2Fshell%2F20160613-034030%2Fimages%2Ffoundation%2Flogos%2Fnyt-logo-185x26.svg%22%20src%3D%20%0A%20%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fa1.nyt.com%2Fassets%2Fshell%2F20160613-034030%2Fimages%2Ffoundation%2Flogos%2Fnyt.png%22%20border%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2Fimage%3E&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) to try it out.

Here is the explanation:

`src=\s*` literal to find all "src=" literals followed by any number of optional spaces

`(\"|\')` group with either a double or single quote.

`[^"']+?` anything that is not a double or single quote (non greedy).

`([^/]+?)` anything that is not a a forward slash (non greedy).

`\.png` literal ".png"

`\1` back reference to the first group `(\"|\')`